# How to fix Admob Unsupported Language issue in Multilanguage app

Tags: android, admob

[image]

Hi, I,ve expense manager app in 8 languages which includes english. Depending on countries it show content in their language, if no found then in english. Google Play App Store Listing Primary language is Azerbaijani. What I must do? Ads is shown in some devices, what if I didn't fix it? or how to fix it?
Is there exists risk of suspending whole account for all apps?

Answer (score 1):

I really don't think they're going to suspend the account for a language support error, I think they're just telling you it's not okay and you need to fix it.

Here you will find the list of languages ​​supported by AdMob (https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9727?hl=en&ref_topic=7383088)

It is not clear from the image if the problem is caused by the app page on the store or the app itself, anyway:

First of all I think you should put English as your primary language in the app page, I think it is also of your interest, it is more likely that people from regions abroad to your supported languages, understand English better than Azerbaijani.

As for the app, you set the language according to the country, in my opinion this can be a error. This is because if the user downloads the app, for example in Azerbaijian, the content is available in Azerbaijian, a language not supported by AdMob. If you instead maybe put a home page where you ask the user to select the language, giving him the opportunity to view the content with a language supported by AdMob, can solve the problem, because in this case you would offer the languages not supported by AdMob as an add-on to your app, and not as a base.

ps. Remember that this is a matter of policy that Google controls, certainly not me. Mine is just a suggestion. I think you knew this even before asking, but better clarify.

Comment: I actually did try this, setting English as a base and another unsupported language as an add-on. It worked for an Android App but not its identical iOS version. The iOS version keeps been rejected but the android passed, identical apps, with the same code. It's frustrating when they don't even clarify where the problem is!